# Value of Application Context Variables Lost on Application Error

Tags: android, memory

I noticed that when my application encounters an error, the value of my application context variables are also reinitialized to its original value (not the updated value). Based from my understanding, this happened because the application was recreated.

**How can I save and restore the values of my application context variables when an application error occurs? I'll also be glad if you could give a more detailed explanation on how things are working on the background of my application when it encounters an error.**

*Note: I read that one of the solution for this is by using SharedPreferences. However, SharedPreferences saves the data even when the application is dead. I don't want to save the data when the application is dead. I only want to save the data when the application is alive or on background.*

Comment: Do you mean an application error that results in a crash, or an error you are catching? I'm a little confused as to whats happening, is your app crashing and losing data or what is happening exactly?

Comment: I am referring to an application error that results in a crash. The error is from an unhandled exception. Yes, my application is crashing and when it resumes, the data is already lose. (The application is automatically recreating itself after the crash.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I save and restore the values of my application context variables when an application error occurs?

First, don't have an unhandled exception.

Second, don't rely on static data members or custom `Application` subclass instances. There are many scenarios in which your process will be terminated and those values go away. They should be used for an in-memory cache of persistent content, and little else.

Sometimes, unhandled exceptions are truly unexpected, but these should be infrequent and usually tied to specific devices (e.g., ran out of storage space). Everything else represents a bug in your app, and you must fix the bugs.

Comment: Exactly, don't try to fix your app to save values to prepare for an unhandled exception, fixed the unhandled exception :).

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks! I will keep that in mind. However, as what you have said, sometimes unhandled exceptions are truly unexpected. Can you suggest a way so that I can keep global variables wherein I can avoid losing data? Also, based from what you have said on your 2nd paragraph, does it mean that variables from a custom Application subclass instance are really expected to behave that way (losing their data when a process is unexpectedly terminated) and there's is nothing I can do about it?

Comment: @Arci: "Can you suggest a way so that I can keep global variables wherein I can avoid losing data?" -- no. Global variables are to be used for a cache for persistent data. "there's is nothing I can do about it?" -- of course. This is the behavior in every program in every operating system ever created, AFAIK. If your app crashes, your memory goes "poof".

Comment: @Jack: Yes, I'll catch the unhandled exceptions. But I also want to make sure not to lose any data when my application suddenly encounters an unexpected error.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for making it clear to me. But I'm just wondering why is my activity being recreated even after it encounters an error? When my application encounters an error, it shows me a dialog asking me to Force Close the activity. When I click the Force Close button, my application is recreated (without asking me) and my previous activity is displayed minus the missing data. I thought if I Force Close my application after an error, it should not be recreated since I already close it?

Comment: @Arci: For whatever reason, the behavior you see is what the Android engineers implemented. Personally, I would have returned control to whatever application preceded it on the back stack (or the home screen, if there is no such application). But, they didn't ask me. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare: LOL. Actually, the activity wherein my application returns to after an error is kinda random so I only referred to it as previous activity as the only thing I'm sure is that the activity can be found on the stack. But, yeah, I'll also prefer it to return on the home screen since the data is lose anyway. Thank you very much for your help! I thought I wasn't able to do something on my application making it behave that way.